# Hibernate can't select need column in table2 across table1?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

my problem is next. I have two table. Table1 that name "Instructor" and Table2 that name "User".
When i displaying information in my template, i need retrieve information about user from table Instructor.

My entity Instructor join column to users
`@Entity
@Table (name = "Instructor")
public class Instructor {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column (name = "instructor_id", nullable = false)
private Long instructorId;

@Basic
@Column (name = "name", nullable = false, length = 45)
private String firstName;

@Basic  
@Column (name = "lastName", nullable = false, length = 45)
private String lastName;

@Basic
@Column (name = "summary", nullable = false, length = 45)
private String instructorSummary;

@OneToMany (mappedBy = "instructor", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set <Course> courses = new HashSet<>();

@OneToOne (cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JoinColumn (name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", nullable = false)
private User user; `
```

Dao layer when i have Exception
 `@Query (nativeQuery=true, value = "select i from Instructor as i where i.user.userEmail =:userEmail") Instructor findInstructByuserEmail (@Param ("userEmail") String userEmail);`

User Entity

`@Entity
@Table (name = "users")
public class User {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column (name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private Long userId;

@Basic
@Column (name = "email", nullable = false, length = 96, unique = true)
private String userEmail;

@Basic
@Column (name = "password", nullable = false, length = 96)
private String userPassword;

@ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinTable (name = "user_role", 
                               joinColumns = {@JoinColumn (name = "user_id")}, 
                               inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn (name = "role_id")})
private Set <Role> roles = new HashSet<>();


@OneToOne (mappedBy = "user")
private Student student;

@OneToOne (mappedBy = "user")
private Instructor instructor;`
```

Couple time i change Query in Dao layer, but it does't help me.

My Stack trace

In there Hibernate create request !
Hibernate: select i from Instructor as i where i.user.userEmail =?
2023-01-23T14:30:30.682+02:00  WARN 32888 --- [nio-8071-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
2023-01-23T14:30:30.682+02:00 ERROR 32888 --- [nio-8071-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'i' in 'field list'
2023-01-23T14:30:30.688+02:00 ERROR 32888 --- [nio-8071-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select i from Instructor as i where i.user.userEmail =?]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause

and than i give Exception !
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'i' in 'field list'

Also if you know good material, about Query it will be very useful for me, tnx!

Comment: `select i.* from ...` missing star to tell SQL you want all columns

Comment: @grekier the OP does not manually create the sql statement, it is the ORM that does it.

Comment: @Shadow I thought that ORM was bypassed when the query is marked as native=true

Comment: @grekier In first case when i.* ->  i give exception  Unknown column 'i.user.userEmail' in 'where clause'

Comment: @Shadow In second when i delete query native=true, i give exception EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method getInstructorId() on null context object

Comment: Native means that you need to join the tables yourself: `select i.* from Instructor as i join users as u on u.user_id = i.user_id where u.email = userEmail`. You might need to update a column name but the point is that, when nativeQuery is true, the query should be the same as you would run it in an SQL client (with column names and not variable names from your classes) except for the parameter value you pass to the query.

Comment: Again the same exception, Unknown column 'userEmail' in 'where clause'